# How to deep clone in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I found one solution that is just related to one relationship but I have a hierarchy of models is ...

```
Board -> Task -> Card ->{coments,files,labels},{checklist}-> checklistitems
```

my question is that whenever I copy board or task or anything subsequent childrens should get **copied** and **referenced** to new Item.

Give me just Hint to do that...!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone the model then loop the original's relations and set them to the clone. Use the `replicate` method on the model to start.

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_replicate

```
$clonedBoard = $board->replicate();

foreach($board->tags as $tag)
{
    $clonedBoard->tags()->attach($tag);
    // you may set the timestamps to the second argument of attach()
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got tags as empty.So can you suggest another method?